# Document metadata are replaced after uploading document again in o365

Tags: 2013, file-upload, office-365

I have created a document library in o365. In o365 a new button is showing at the top of the document library "Upload". Now I have uploaded a document and added some metadata to that. Now when I am uploading document again using "Upload" button it is replacing all existing values.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in versioning enabled Document Library.

[Document Properties not carry to new version](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/document-properties-not-carry-to-new-version)

http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2010-versioning/