# When I am uploading a Word Document in Document Library - Custom Columns values are getting blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, properties, sharepoint-library, modern-document-library

I have uploaded the Word document on SharePoint Document Library (Modern Site), my Library has following columns:

- Title
- ADDS
- LBB
- Category

**Step 1:** After uploading the file for the first time, I have filled the values in these columns on SharePoint.

**Step 2:** Again, I have uploaded the same file, now above columns values got blank.

**Issue with Title** > I can understand this.... *Title* is MS Word property as well and it will be overwritten *(As per this - [Document Properties not carry to new version](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/document-properties-not-carry-to-new-version)).*

But why my other custom columns values are getting blank???

> Note: This issue is coming only for MS Office files (DOC, PPT, XLS, etc.). However it's working as expected for other file formats - .pdf, .jpg, .zip, etc

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I follow the steps in your post and then I encounter the same issue as yours.

It cannot upload the file with the same file name, if I click the “Replace” and then the values in the custom columns will disappear.

Then I suggest you could submit a service request in the office 365 admin center.

[image]